# Interpreting $P(\alpha|\text{data})\propto P(\text {data} | \alpha)\cdot P(\alpha)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, bayesian

In the context of posterior and prior probabilities, one has $P(\alpha|\text{data})\propto P(\text {data} | \alpha)\cdot P(\alpha)$. What confuses me here is that probability is defined for events, and $\alpha$ is not an event, it is a parameter. But then how to interpret $P(\alpha)$ and  $P(\alpha|\text{data})$ if $\alpha$ is not an event?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a parameter with a discrete prior distribution and the data comes from a discrete distribution, then you have $P(\alpha=a \mid \text{data}=x)=\frac1{P(\text {data}=x)} P(\text {data}=x \mid \alpha=a)\cdot P(\alpha=a)$ as Bayes' formula or conditional probability applied to events; here $P(\text {data}=x) = \sum_a P(\text {data}=x \mid \alpha=a)\cdot P(\alpha=a)$.  This can be extended to continuous distributions and their densities.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864150/why-is-the-formula-f-xyxy-fracp-yxyx-f-xxp-yy-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with using capital $P$ in this context, which can be confusing. Typically, $P(\alpha)$ and $P(\alpha|\text{data})$ are pdfs/pmfs of the parameters $\alpha$ and $\alpha|\text{data}$.

For example, suppose $\alpha\sim\text{Beta}(\kappa,\lambda)$ and $N\sim \text{Binomial}(n,\alpha)$, then in your notation, $$P(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha^{\kappa-1}(1-\alpha)^{\lambda-1}}{B(\kappa,\lambda)}.$$ I would prefer to use the notation $f(\alpha)$ instead of $P(\alpha)$, because $P$ can look like a probability, which, as you said, should be probability of an event. I've also seen authors use $\pi(\alpha)$, where $\pi$ is for prior.

Similarly, if the data we observe is that $N=k$, then $\alpha|\text{data}\sim\text{Beta}(\kappa+k,\lambda+n-k)$, and $$P(\alpha|\text{data})\propto\alpha^{\kappa+k-1}(1-\alpha)^{\lambda+n-k-1}.$$

In this context, $\text{data}$ is often also an outcome, not an event, and $P(\text{data}|\alpha)$ is the value of a pdf/pmf.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Just want to add a remark. More traditionally, one uses $p(\cdot \mid \alpha)$ to denote the *pdf* of the sampling distribution (distribution of the observations) which depends on the parameter $\alpha$ and $\pi$ to denote the *pdf* on the parameter space. Then the formula becomes $\pi(\alpha|\text{data})\propto p(\text {data} | \alpha)\cdot \pi(\alpha)$. Note: you wrote "$\sim$" instead of "$\propto$".