# Why is the formula $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{P_{Y|X}(y|x) f_X(x)}{P_Y(y)}$ true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Suppose we have a random sample $X=(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ which depends on $\theta$, treated as a value of the random variable $\Theta$.  The posterior pdf is given by $$f_{\Theta | X}(\theta|x)=\frac{f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)f_\Theta(\theta)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,\theta)d\theta}$$

where $f_\Theta$ is the prior pdf of the random variable $\Theta$.

All $f$s in this case are pdfs, and it is clear where this formula is coming from: we just need to express $f(x,\theta)$ in two different ways and set them equal to each other.

But what if $f_\Theta$ is a pdf while $f_{X|\Theta}$ is a pmf? For example, maybe the random sample in this case is the result of some number of coin flips. In that case, each  $X_i$ is a discrete random variable, and $f_{X|\Theta}$ should be a pmf rather than a pdf.

At the same time, $f_\Theta$  could be something like $f_\Theta(\theta)=\text{const}\cdot \theta^2(1-\theta)^2$ for some $\text{const}$ which makes it a pdf.

So my question is: if in the displayed formula above, $f_\Theta$ and $f_{\Theta|X}$ are pdfs but $f_{X|\Theta}$ is a pmf, then the formula takes the form

$$f_{\Theta | X}(\theta|x)=\frac{p_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)f_\Theta(\theta)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,\theta)d\theta}.$$

And if so, how to prove such a formula that has both pdfs and pmfs in it? It also becomes unclear what $f(x,\theta)$ should mean in this context.

**Addition**: in [this note](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/ma218/bayes1.pdf), the author is essentially saying that (in my notation) $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)$ is

> a conditional probability or a conditional density depending on
> whether $X$ is a continuous or discrete random variable

But again, what is the justification for the formula when $X$ is discrete?..

**Addition 2:** [This page](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter9/9_1_1_prior_and_posterior.php) also says (without giving a reason) that in my first displayed formula at the very top, we can replace pdf with pmf for one of the variables.

Comment: If $\Theta$ has a continuous distribution and $X$ has a discrete distribution, your $f(x,\theta)$ is neither a joint density nor a joint p.m.f.  Better to try something like $f_{\Theta \mid X}(\theta \mid x)=\dfrac{\mathbb P(X=x\mid\Theta=\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)}{\int\limits_{\theta=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P(X=x\mid\Theta=\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)\,d\theta}$  since  $\mathbb P(X=x)=\int\limits_{\theta=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P(X=x\mid\Theta=\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)\,d\theta$

Comment: Okay, that settles the question of what $f(x,\theta)$ should mean in this context (or what it should be replaced with), but it still remains unclear why both of your formulas are true.

Comment: So the question becomes why you can say $\mathbb P(X=x)\,f_{\Theta \mid X}(\theta \mid x)={\mathbb P(X=x\mid\Theta=\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)}$.  See it as something like $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac1{\epsilon}\mathbb P(X=x)\,\mathbb P(\theta \le \Theta \le \theta+\epsilon \mid X=x) = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac1{\epsilon}\mathbb P(X=x\mid \theta \le \Theta \le \theta+\epsilon)\,\mathbb P(\theta \le \Theta \le \theta+\epsilon)$ where the equality without the limits or $\frac1\epsilon$ is because both sides are equal to $\mathbb P(X=x, \theta \le \Theta \le \theta+\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Henry Thank you! However, I think I don't fully understand passing to the limits. For example, why do we need to divide by $\epsilon$ before taking the limits? And why e.g. $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\mathbb{P}(\theta \leq \Theta \leq \theta+\epsilon)=f_\Theta(\theta)$?

Comment: That last one is close to taking the derivative of the CDF to get the density.  For small and shrinking $\epsilon$ and a continuous distribution $\mathbb{P}(\theta \leq \Theta \leq \theta+\epsilon)$ will be very small and heading towards $0$ so you need to offset it with the large and increasing $\frac1\epsilon$

Comment: I'm not good at understanding informal reasonings, could we make the following argument instead? $\Pr(\theta \leq \Theta \leq \theta + \epsilon)=\int_\theta^{\theta+\epsilon}f_\Theta(t)dt=F_\Theta(\theta+\epsilon)-F_\Theta(\theta)$, and dividing by $\epsilon$ and taking limits would give us $F_\Theta'(\theta)$, which is equal to $f_\Theta(\theta)$.

And one other thing that I still don't understand is your second equality from your first comment (the one about $\Pr(X=x)$. Any hints on that, @Henry?

Comment: Your first point is correct for a continuous distribution. On $\mathbb P(X=x)=\int\limits_{\theta=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P(X=x\mid\Theta=\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)\,d\theta$, this is simply finding $\mathbb P(X=x)$  as a function of $X$ based on $\mathbb P(X=x\mid\Theta=\theta)$ as a conditional function of $X$